# Managing Room Calendars in Exchange/Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

When a meeting is created that conflicts with another meeting on the Room calendar, is it possible to have the conflicting meeting forwarded to a delegate for a manual resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the settings on the Room Account.  There should be an option to not allow conflicting meetings, make sure it's checked.  Also check to see that you don't have any and/or all users in the "Out of Policy" meeting requests section.  If it's supposed to be an Auto-accept style room you'll want that section to be cleared.

Comment: There's an option to "Allow conflicting meetings" and that is not checked - I assume that's why conflicting meetings go into "tentative" status. I do allow people in the office to make "Out of Policy" requests because there might be a need to book the room for a week, a month - who knows? i don't want to block the room from any request. I just want the admin to be able to make the final call.

Comment: It's the out of policy requests that's causing the issue I bet.  It think that basically says, any users placed here do not have to adhere to my defined settings.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. For a small group (home office employees), I want them to be able to schedule anything they like at any time. If there's a conflict, it'll be marked tentative and the admin will get an email to approve or cancel it. Does Microsoft envision it working some other way?

Comment: The admin's not going to get an email.  There's generally not a delegate set on an Auto-accept calendar.

Comment: So either Exchange manages the room or a delegate does - no middle ground? And if exchange does it, you either have a lot of conflicts to be managed by individual users or you have a lot of angry users carefully scheduling around each other in the calendar? Not the best system in the world... Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's how it works.